# How to get text from lineEdit in Pyside?

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyside

I'm learning Pyside and I can't seem to get text from a QLineEdit into my own method so that I can input it into a query etc. I know it has to do with lineEdit.text(), but it isn't seeming to work. Do I need to associate it with a signal before the text will go into my variable??

This is the type of thing I've been trying. Do I need a textChanged signal to get it to update or something?? I've tried adding self.line , but that didn't work either, a little rusty on object oriented programming.

```
line=QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
myVar = line.text()
```

A short code example would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be creating the object and using it right afterwards. Of course, you get an empty string from `text()`; it doesn't work like that.

You should add the `QLineEdit` to a GUI, let the user do something with it and then obtain the text with `QLineEdit.text()`. To know when exactly the user changed the text, yes, you should connect to the `QLineEdit.textEdited` slot.

Here is a full example that uses such a mechanism to copy all the text from a `QLineEdit` to a `QLabel` as soon as it's modified.

```
import sys

from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.line_edit = QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)

        self.label = QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.line_edit.textChanged.connect(self.line_edit_text_changed)

        self.show()

    def line_edit_text_changed(self, text):
        self.label.setText(text)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mw = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

This is example shows how you can connect your own function to a slot. But since a `QLabel` has a [`setText`](http://doc.qt-project.org/qlabel#text-prop) slot, we could just do `self.line_edit.textChanged.connect(self.line_edit.setText)` and not define a function.

P.S. You really should read some tutorial; I found [**this one**](http://zetcode.com/gui/pysidetutorial/) very useful.

Comment: I don't suppose you could show QLineEdit.text() being used with QLineEdit.textEdited signal could you??

Comment: Oh I have been reading the tutorials, and it's not the moving of data between pre-existing pyside items with their existing signals and slots that gets me. It's moving the data into my own variables to go to a database etc. What I have on my screen is very very close to what you wrote, I'll keep staring at it as I must be close. Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: That last one should be `self.line_edit.textChanged.connect(self.label.setText)` (label instead of line_edit)